# KeyEvent on key pressed twitche

Tags: javafx, event-handling

IntelliJ has a feature where an event is triggered when the `Shift` key is pressed twice (called: Search anywhere).

How can one implement an `EventHandler` for such an event in JavaFX? Is there something out of the box or is there another way to do that?

Comment: Just check how much time has passed between two consecutive events of the corresponding type.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
private boolean shiftPressedOnceRecently = false ;
private static final Duration DOUBLE_KEY_PRESS_TIME = Duration.millis(250);

// ...

Scene scene = ... ;
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if (e.getKeyCode() != KeyCode.SHIFT) return ;
    if (shiftPressedOnceRecently) {
        // do whatever you need for two presses of shift key...
    } else {
        shiftPressedOnceRecently = true ;
        PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(DOUBLE_KEY_PRESS_TIME);
        delay.setOnFinished(evt -> { shiftPressedOnceRecently = false ; });
        delay.play();
    }
});
```